# print first 80 char in a line in unix pipe

Tags: perl, sed, awk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Truncate stdin line length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137313/truncate-stdin-line-length)

I have been looking for an `awk` or `perl` (or maybe `sed`?) one-liner to print the first 80 char in a line to be used in as:

```
cat myfile.txt | # awk/perl here
```

I'm guessing something like `perl -pe 'print $_[0..80]'` should work but I'm no good in perl.

**EDIT** `perl -pe 'print $_[0..80]` does not work and I don't know why. That's why I asked this question. I feel like explaining after all those silent downvotes..

Also `cat myfile.txt` is just to demonstrate that the command should be in a pipe, I'm actually using some other output.

Comment: Because somebody thinks your question is [not a real question](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#close).

Comment: @Tichodroma that's the part I don't get it..

Comment: @WilliamPursell seems pretty close although this question got more comprehensive answers. I wish I could think of the word 'truncate', would be easy to find an answer then.

Comment: `perl -pe'print substr $_, 0, 80'`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**cut:**

```
cut -c1-80 your_file
```

**awk:**

```
awk '{print substr($0,0,80)}' your_file
```

**sed:**

```
sed -e 's/^\(.\{80\}\).*/\1/' your_file
```

**perl:**

```
perl -lne 'print substr($_,0,80)' your_file
```

or:

```
perl -lpe 's/.{80}\K.*//s' your_file
```

**grep:**

```
grep -o "^.\{80\}" your_file
```

Comment: Add `-l` switch and remove `"\n"` from your perl solution. You can also use `perl -plwe 's/.{0,80}\K.*//s'`

Answer (score 2):

Use [`cut`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/cut-invocation.html#cut-invocation), to get the first characters:

```
$ cut -c1-80 myfile.txt
```

If you want the first *bytes*, use `-b`:

```
$ cut -b1-80 myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Use as following:

```
$ cat myfile.txt | awk '{print substr($0,0,80)}'
```

Other way is:

```
$ awk '{print substr($0,0,80)}' x
```

Here no need of `cat`, `awk` can read from files.

Comment: No need to `cat` a file into `awk`.

Comment: @Tichodroma : Why not? It required na.. am I missing something!..

Comment: All tools like `awk` can read from files.

Comment: @Tichodroma: I have cheeked ..Its working fine..

Comment: Of course it is working. But it is not *necessary*.

Comment: @Tichodroma : Thanks ..I updated the other in answer too..

Answer (score 1):

One of the cut/sed/awk solutions is probably right for you but you may also be interested in fold since it lets you wrap lines and truncate then at the space preceding the character count rather than mid-word at exactly the character count if you like:

```
$ cat file
the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog's back

$ cat file | fold -w29
the quick brown fox jumped ov
er the lazy dog's back

$ cat file | fold -s -w29
the quick brown fox jumped
over the lazy dog's back

$ cat file | fold -w29 | head -1
the quick brown fox jumped ov

$ cat file | fold -s -w29 | head -1
the quick brown fox jumped
```

By the way, I would absolutely NOT use "cat" as shown above, I'm assume the OP has some other commands writing to stdout and is just using "cat" to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: `fold` seems useful but `head -1` only returns the first line (doesn't quite work for multiple line outputs).

Comment: and yes btw, I was using `cat` just for demonstration. I have edited my question to say that, thanks..